# Excel 2007 matching data

Tags: excel

I have an issue in Excel 2007 and i'm not sure how to get my end result.

I have 1 Workbook with 2 sheets.

I've already tried the `VLookup`, but it returns an `#N/A`.

First worksheet, `Sheet1` has Item #, Description, Size and UPC Code. 
`Sheet2` has UPC Codes, but it was for inventory, so they scanned the same UPC Code multiple times, so it repeats, some for 20, others only 1.
[image: Sheet1]

So I need to "Count" how many times the UPC Code appears in `Sheet2`. I guess that would be the first step.

Next, I need to match the UPC Codes in `Sheet2` to the UPC Codes in `Sheet1` along with telling us the Item #, Description, & Size that correlates to that UPC Code.

[image: Sheet2]

`Sheet1` Column `A` is Item #, Column `B` is Description, Column `C` is Size, Column `D` is UPC Code.

`Sheet2`, Column `A` is UPC Code from the inventory scan.

So my end result will be the Item #, Description, Size, UPC Code, and Qty of the scanned UPC inventory.

Can anyone help with this?

**Edit**
If I can just get the data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`, I can get the count by UPC. So I just need help getting the data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` using Column `D` in `Sheet1` to match it up with `Sheet2` column `A`. I need to copy `Sheet1` Column `A` through Column `D` to `Sheet2` Column `B` thru `E` based on the unique identifier in Column `A` of `Sheet2`, and Column `D` of `Sheet1`. I've tried the `VLOOKUP` formula: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$40019,1,FALSE)` but it returns `#N/A` but when I try to find the value in `Sheet1`, I can. When I change the formula to be: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$40019,1,TRUE)` it returns `55942` which is an item # in `Sheet1` column `A` but it doesn't match the UPC's. Images are below and above.

Comment: Add some images (links to imgur) and your formulas you've tried to make it easier to see whats going in but it sounds like you could use `countif` for the count and vlookup to bring the data over.

Comment: Please add some images of the data, or maybe you can use this [site](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to provide part of the data.

Comment: Added photo's to the original post.

Comment: Formula's I've used: =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$40019,1,FALSE) it returns #N/A.

Comment: Found out why it was returning #N/A; Sheet 1, the UPC is stored as a text... Now my Vlookup works.